Excel PowerQuery locking source file for Git
I am using PowerQuery in Excel to load a CSV config file.
= Csv.Document(File.Contents("myFile.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=4, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])

This file is held under version control in a Git repo.
With Excel open (and the csv data loaded in PowerQuery) I can edit the local csv file separately in VS Code, and save it without any issue (ie I am NOT told the file is in use by Excel). However if I try to Discard changes in the VS Code Source Control tab, I get an error:
> git checkout -q -- myFile.csv
error: unable to unlink old 'myFile.csv': Invalid argument

However I can manually revert the file, save it, and Source Control now sees it as unchanged.
If I close the Excel sheet (but not the Excel instance), the Git error remains, but if I close Excel entirely I can now Discard the changes in VS Code (and also pull the latest version from the Git server).
It is as if Excel (the application, not a specific sheet) is holding a weak lock on the CSV file, which allows overwriting, but somehow conflicts with Git.
Has anyone seen anything similar?
Windows 10, Excel version 2302, VS Code 1.90.0

This worked for a colleague: "try this. add the step "reverse the rows" and double it. we will get the same query that we wanted. and the mashup container loader will be closed."
Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/nwop8c/comment/j7xdgeg/
